# maven-jaxb1-plugin error while executing in jdk1.6 and maven 3.0.3

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I am running a maven script which uses maven-jaxb1-plugin version 1.0.rc-11 to generate the jaxb classes from xsd. The script was running successfully in the java version 1.4 and maven version less than 3 . Now the same script when run in java version 1.6 and maven version 3.0.3 environment throws an exception **

> A required class was missing while executing
>   org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2:maven-jaxb1-plugin:1.0.rc-11:generate:com.sun.msv.grammar.Grammar

**
All the dependencies for this plugin are available in my repository.Still I am getting this error.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.parsers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb1-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.rc-11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>response.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is it like maven-jaxb1-plugin can not be used in jdk1.6 and maven 3.0.3 environment.Any help is much appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: Should that `maven-jaxb1-plugin` version be `1.0-rc11`?  That's what I find in the main repository.

Answer (score 0):

The class that it says it is missing, `com.sun.msv.grammar.Grammar`, is present in `jaxb1-impl.jar` according to findjar.com:

http://www.findjar.com/class/com/sun/msv/grammar/Grammar.html

That class does not seem to be present in `jaxb-impl.jar`:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/1.0.6

It does seem to be present in `jaxb1-impl.jar`:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb1-impl/2.0

So maybe change your dependency to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb1-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I changed the dependency to jaxb1-impl jar but still the error exists

Comment: Can you post your `response.xsd`?